# Appium: How to handle app redirecting to another app and back again

Tags: java, android, redirect, appium

I'm currently creating a test script using Appium and I am stuck in automating the scenario below which involves redirection from 1 app to another.

1. Press a button in App1 which will redirect the user to App2
2. Validate fields in App2 and press a button that will return user to App1
3. Perform some more tests in App1

My script is failing in Step 2 since the android driver does not recognize the UI elements in App2. Can someone help me in how to handle this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: you have to use `onActivityResult()` for handle this.

Comment: @ChiragSavsani can u give an example code so that it will benefit others

Comment: @karthick23 There are many example available online. Like open camera and take photo video, login with social media through native app and back to our app etc...

Answer (score 0):

If redirection is manually possible by pressing the `back` button then one way how to implement this is by `back` driver command: `driver.navigate().back()`